# Spring 400 Bad Request When Sending Multipart Request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, spring-rest

I am attempting to call from Service Consumer (Project 1) to Service Provider (Project 2) with Multipart data using spring REST service, but I am receiving 400 bad request error. Both the services are running in my machine. Below is my code snippet. I cannot able to service provide code since this is using by third party system.

**Service Consumer:**

```
    @Override
    public void callFileAPI(byte[] pdf) {
        String response = null;
        HttpStatus httpStatus = null;
        try {
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            map.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(pdf));
            //map.add("request", "");
            
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            String url = "http://xxxx/api/mpFile";

            final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
            response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, String.class);
            //response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, map, String.class);
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Service Provider:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mpFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String mpFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
        String respStr = "OK";
        try {
            System.out.println("File obj : "+file);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return respStr;
    }
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:708)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:388)
```